# Sort by a column that has intervals in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a df with a column that has intervals:

***1-25* 

*26-50*  

*51-100*  

*100-200*  

*More than 200***

When I tried to sort in ascending order in R, it looks like

***1-25* 

*100-200*  

*26-50*  

*51-100*  

*More than 200***

It sorts according to first numbers. How I can fix it?

Comment: You'll need the start and end interval as different columns if you want to do anything meaningful with this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a data frame with those levels, out of order:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                 intervals = c("26-50", "More than 200", "51-100", 
                               "1-25", "100-200"))
df
#      intervals
#1         26-50
#2 More than 200
#3        51-100
#4          1-25
#5       100-200
```

We might add a helper column for sorting:

```
df$num = readr::parse_number(df$intervals)
df[order(df$num),]
#      intervals num
#4          1-25   1
#1         26-50  26
#3        51-100  51
#5       100-200 100
#2 More than 200 200
```

Or we could make the interval into a `factor` so it will have a built-in order besides alphabetical:

```
df$intervals_f <- factor(df$intervals, levels = c("1-25", "26-50", 
                         "51-100", "100-200", "More than 200"))

df[order(df$intervals_f),]
#      intervals num   intervals_f
#4          1-25   1          1-25
#1         26-50  26         26-50
#3        51-100  51        51-100
#5       100-200 100       100-200
#2 More than 200 200 More than 200
```

Comment: Adding a helper column is a good idea but 
df[order(df$intervals_f),] still gives same wrong order if implemented without "num" column.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, I'm not sure why not for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of words / upper values in range / whitespace / coerce to numeric / reorder / store as new vector of name "intervals", punch it into a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(intervals = df[order(as.numeric(trimws(gsub("[-].*|[a-zA-Z]+", "", df$intervals)))),], stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
                 intervals = c("26-50", "More than 200", "51-100", 
                               "1-25", "100-200"))
```